# Eclipse Luna Does Not Highlight Matching Braces

Tags: eclipse

I just started using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) on Mac OS X v10.9.5. I am editing JavaScript code, and need for the editor to highlight matching pairs of braces. This feature has always been enabled by default in my past experience with Eclipse.

I have scrutinized the Preferences without success, including:

Java > Editor

Nothing seems to work. Is this issue a bug in Eclipse Luna? I ran updates to no effect. Is there an extension that would add the desired feature? Braces highlighting is one of the few fancy features I make use of.

Comment: Does this help http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_syntax_coloring.htm

Comment: Thanks for the response. JavaScript does not appear in the Syntax Coloring dialog. I will work on trying to get it added there.

Comment: This issue resolved when I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled the full Java EE edition. I then re-created my project as a JavaScript project.